# Find with concat in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, find, concatenation

I have a very simple question on MongoDB.

I have a collection that has 2 fields in each doc. I want to make a find like this:

```
db.mycoll.find({}, { my_new_f : { $concat : ["$f1", ".", "$f2"]}})
```

Why such a query is not supported? (Or am I doing something wrong?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$concat`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/#exp._S_concat) is an operator that's used with `aggregate`, not `find`, and `find` projections have no support for derived fields like this.

To do this with `aggregate` you would do something like:

```
db.mycoll.aggregate({$project: { my_new_f : { $concat : ["$f1", ".", "$f2"]}}})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.mycoll.find({$expr:{$eq:["value", {$concat:["$field1", "$field2"]}]}})
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Comment: This doesn't address the question. OP wants a projection that includes a new derived field.

Comment: add explanation pls

Answer (score 1):

From MongoDB version 4.4, [aggregation projections are supported for find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#use-aggregation-expression). This would now be correct:

```
db.mycoll.find({}, { my_new_f : { $concat : ["$f1", ".", "$f2"]}})
```